# Error in shapiro.test : sample size must be between

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have a vector, in R, with 1521298 points, which have to be tested for normality. I chose the Shapiro-Wilk test, but the R function `shapiro.test()` says:

> Error in shapiro.test(z_scores) : sample size must be between 3 and 5000

Do you know any other function to test it or how to circumvent this issue?

Comment: (1) there are plenty of other normality-testing functions in R (e.g. see the `nortest` package).  (2) can you comment on why you're doing this test? I can almost guarantee that you will reject the hypothesis of normality with a very low p-value if you have such a large data set.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the Central Limit Theorem ... a question like this would be more appropriate for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) (the CLT says that the distribution of a *sum of a large number of independent values* tends to Normality, not that the *distribution of a large number of values* tends to Normality ...)

Comment: the Shapiro-Wilk test is a good choice. This test has the best power for testing a data set for normality. And actually the larger the dataset the better the test result with Shapiro-Wilk. The test is limited to max 5000 sample as you had to learn already (the original test was limited to 50! samples). The only thing you could do is to choose less than 5000 points randomly from your data set to get those tested. Is your data set sorted or randomly arranged?

Comment: @JFS, I don't agree with what you're saying: apply the shapiro-wilk test on several large random samples from normal distribution and you'll see that most of them will have a low p-value. There are good explanations of what's happening with large samples [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless).

Comment: @GathG, the problem with testing a set of data for a certain distribution has always uncertainties. The Shapiro-Wilk test is one of the few objective tests with the highest power. This doesn't mean that this test will not fail. But other test are even worse. The larger the number of sample the more sensitive are deviations to the result which could actually lead to a "wrong" result like small p-values even for known normal distributed sample set. But, the smaller the sample set the larger the risk to habe non-normal distributed samples sets which will not get rejected...

Comment: ... At the end there is no right or wrong. Each test is not perfect but (at least for me) the use of Shapiro-Wilk showed the best performance compared to other tests.

Answer (score 14):

Shapiro test cannot done using more than 5.000 records.

You can try to do the shapiro test using only the first 5.000 samples.
IF it can help you, use the code like this:

```
shapiro.test(beaver2$temp[0:5000])
```

But pay attention, the test will use only the first 5.000 samples of your data.

In the other hand, if you need to use all the records of your sample, use another similar test, like Anderson-Darling normality test.
You also can execute both and compare, like this script below:

```
# clean workspace
rm(list=ls())

# Install required packages:
install.packages('nortest')

#Model data tho use
ModelData = beaver2$temp

#Do shapiro test with only the first 5000 records
shapiro.test(ModelData[0:5000])$p.value

#Anderson-Darling normality test
library(nortest)
ad.test(ModelData)$p.value
```

Comment: The Anderson-Darling test has a similar problem with the Shapiro Wilk test. For large samples, you are most likely to reject the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 10):

You can try, Anderson-Darling normality test, which works for larger sample sizes.

```
library(nortest)
ad.test(data$variable)
```