# Shapiro Wilk in Rstudio mentions that my sample size must be between 3 and 5000

Tags: r

I want to test the normality of gene expression (ki) for 4 groups (oxygen, scaff, cyt and time).

Below my data set

```
data <- na.omit(ki67_Victor)
# Define variables

oxygen <-as.factor (data$Oxygen)
scaff <-as.factor(data$Scaffold)
cyt <-as.factor(data$Cytokines)
time <-as.factor(data$Time)
ki = data$`ki-67`

DT <- data.table(data)

DT[, .(W = shapiro.test(ki67)$statistic, P.value = shapiro.test(ki67)$p.value),
   by = .(Oxygen, Scaffold,Cytokines, Time)]
```

Normally this test works but as soon as I have 3 or more groups, I get an error that my sample size must be between 3 and 5000. My sample size is 178 so R incorrectly gives me this error in my opinion.

I have no clue what to do. In previous data sets I got this error when I had NANs but now I don't have any.

Comment: This link might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217306/error-in-shapiro-test-sample-size-must-be-between

Comment: could we please have a [mcve] ?

Comment: does each of your groups have at least 3 samples? perhaps one of your groups does not fulfill this requirement.

Comment: not very good with data table, but it looks like you might be effectively trying apply the function over the *interaction* of the 4 variables you specified. It looks like you should be grouping by a *factor* that indicates which group each observation belongs to?